# How do I hide this drop down menu using javascript/jquery when any area outside of it is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Right now my I click #headerNav and menu drops down as expected but when I click any where outside of the menu it has no effect.

Where am I going wrong?

**My HTML:**

```
   <header>
      <div id='headerContent'>
        <div id='LogoHolder'>
        </div>
        <nav id='headerNav'>
          <ul>
            <li id='photoThumbnail'></li>
            <li id='currentUser'>
              <ul class="dropdownMenu">
                <li>link1</li>
                <li>link2</li>
                <li>link3</li>
                <li>link4</li>
                <li>link5</li>
                <li>link6</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
```

**My JS:**

```
$("#headerNav").click(function(e) {
  return $(".dropdownMenu").addClass('homeMenuClass').toggle()(e.stopPropagation());
});
$("html").click(function(e) {
  return $(".dropDownMenu").addClass('menuGone').toggle();
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.homeMenuClass {
                position:absolute;
            background-color:white;
            border: {
                        top: 2px solid $main-background-color;
                 right: 1px solid $main-background-color;
                 bottom: 1px solid $main-background-color;
                     left: 1px solid $main-background-color;
            }
            top:37px;
            right:-40px;
            height:245px;
            width:200px;
            font-weight:bold;
            color:gray;

            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
                        box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;

                  a {
                    color:gray;
                  }
}

.menuGone {
    display:none !important;
}
```

I have looked at similar questions and tried solutions but none seem to work.
Kind regards

**Update:** (This is working 100% the way I want it to but for some reason it feels like I'm going about things the wrong way. e.g. the addClass('homeMenuClass') line.. Slightly confused about the toggle variable function.

```
$(function() {
       var button = $("#headerNav"),
    menu = $(".dropdownMenu", button),
    toggle = function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (menu.hasClass('open')) {
            menu.toggle().removeClass('open').addClass('homeMenuClass');
        } else {
            menu.toggle().addClass('open').addClass('homeMenuClass');
        }
    };

button.click(toggle);

$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (($(e.target).parents('#headerNav').length === 0 || e.target.id === 'headerNav') && menu.hasClass('open')) {
        toggle.apply(button, [e]);
    }
});

});
```

Comment: Where is the CSS that belongs to this?

Comment: Yep it's SASS, I tried to strip it down to normal CSS as much as I could, forgot a few things. by the way homeMenuClass isn't part of the HTML. It's just a class I define in my css file so I can apply it to the menu when it gets shown with javascript as it looks all wonky without that class.

Comment: It has the exact same settings as the dropdownMenu class except the display: none part. The dropdownMenu class is only used when a user has js disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/kKRVY/) that does what you want.

Important notes

- I defined the toggle function seperately to be able to reuse it.
- Added the word 'Test' so I had something to click to open the menu
- Always pass the event object to the toggle function since it needs to stop propagation to prevent an infinite loop.

The function is layed out as following:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    "use strict";
    var $menu = $("#headerNav"),
        $dd = $(".dropdownMenu", $menu),
        //Ddefine function for toggling display so we can reuse it
        toggle = function(e) {
            // Stop propagation will prevent the event to 'bubble' up through its parents again
            // In this case it is needed to prevent an eternal loop (well jQuery will return an error at some point but regardless, this is how we prevent it)
            // Normally click events when triggered are called on the direct element under the mouse, and then its parent, and its parent, because triggering one elements effectively triggers all its parents. Since we catch the click event at the highest level already we should prevent this when it is not needed, or when we click the menu itself, the toggle function will be triggered once because it was clicked and another time because at the highest level, document it might be triggered again
            e.stopPropagation();
            if ($dd.hasClass('homeMenuClass')) {
                $dd.hide().removeClass('homeMenuClass');
            } else {
                $dd.show().addClass('homeMenuClass');
            }
        };

    // Simply binds the already made function to the menu click
    $menu.click(toggle);

    // the document is the highest level in the DOM and most events propagate up till here unless stopped before
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        // Here we check if one of the parents of the target or the target itself is #headernav, if it is the function will be triggered by the menu click
        // If #headerNav is not a parent or the target isn't headerNav itself it means that we clicked somewhere outside of it
        if (($(e.target).parents('#headerNav').length === 0 || e.target.id === 'headerNav') && $dd.hasClass('homeMenuClass')) {

            // Here we take the function toggle and apply $menu to it, make $menu `this` in the context of toggle, this isn't really nessacery for this particular case but I think its neater to call the function in the same context as the normal click would have... 
            // e is passed in an array(the brackets make it an array) as the first argument
            // more on that here:http://trephine.org/t/index.php?title=JavaScript_call_and_apply
            toggle.apply($menu, [e]);
        }
    });

});
```

**Edit**

Changed the function to use your classes and an instant hide/show -> this is what [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) does but it's indescriminate of what state your element is in.

Comment: Hi, added the CSS. I actually need this css added because without it the dropdown menu is in the wrong position and all the styling is messed up. How ever your code works fine. I'd like to understand every piece of it so would it be possible for you to explain each step briefly? I understand some parts of it e.g. setting up the vars and the if statements but the function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); doesn't make much sense to me. Also would it be ok to replace slideUp, slideDown with toggle()? as I prefer to have the menu show instantly or maybe with a slight slight delay.

Comment: Ofcourse I don't particully mind of the exact method of showing/hiding the menu but I'd advice against toggle and keep the switching of the method in your own hands, it's required for checking if the menu is open anyway... Gimme a second, I'll add some more explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for this. After my years of programming I knew one day I would have to learn JS. This answer will be very useful for helping me with my next task.

Comment: No problem, don't shy away of readin up on basics, or stuff that should be basics. Even after years I still re-learn some basic features that make js kick-ass regularly... And each time I learn better/more efficient ways to apply my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks somewhat weird, try this:

```
$("#headerNav").click(function(e) {
  $(".dropdownMenu").addClass('homeMenuClass').show();
});
$("html").click(function(e) {
  $(".dropDownMenu").addClass('menuGone').hide();
});
```

Unsure why you were returning anything from the event handlers and what that last () with preventDefault was about. Also, do you really need to add classes *and* toggle()? Also, I've switched to show/hide instead of toggle as you'll always want to hide when clicking outside and always show when clicking the menu.

Edit: If the classes are used to show/hide the menu you can (like I said) skip the call to toggle/show/hide and just use add/removeClass, like this:

```
$("#headerNav").click(function(e) {
  $(".dropdownMenu").removeClass('menuGone').addClass('homeMenuClass');
});
$("html").click(function(e) {
  $(".dropDownMenu").removeClass('homeMenuClass').addClass('menuGone');
});
```

Edit2: Note that when clicking #headerNav the click will bubble up to html as well unless you do e.stopPropagation(). You could also check in your html click handler if e.target was #headerNav or a child of #headerNav.

Comment: I'll give this a try and report back. That javascript code was what the coffeescript to javascript converter gave me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the onblur() js event.

```
$("#headerNav").blur(function(e) {
    return $(".dropDownMenu").addClass('menuGone').toggle();
});
```

Comment: didn't work either.. does my html area actually have to be clickable? I mean right now it's completely covered by body, header etc.

Answer (score 0):

try removeClass()

```
$("html").click(function(e) {
  return $(".dropDownMenu").removeClass('homeMenuClass');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
$(document).click(function(e) {   
return $(".dropDownMenu").addClass('menuGone').toggle(); 
});
```

Btw, you could use `.on()`, which remplace old event handlers : http://api.jquery.com/on/

It may also be a css problem : is your menuGone class applied ?